# .net XSLT to create worksheets

Tags: .net, xml, excel, xslt

I am trying to export a lot of data to excel.
I need a possibility to separate the data between different worksheets.
I prefer not to be depend on packages like [this](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/), so I thought about XSLT.

Does anyone knows how to create worksheets with XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use XSLT for this, but you will have to output the data in Microsoft Excel XML format, which is supported from versions of Microsoft Excel 2002 onwards.

[Microsoft XML Spreadsheet Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

You can also find a useful sample on Wikipedia

[Microsoft Office XML Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)

How the XSLT is coding generally depends on the structure of the XML you wish to transform. Here is a very simple example, which transforms to one sheet:

```
<data>
   <row>
      <cell>1.1</cell><cell>12</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>2.1</cell><cell>2.2</cell>
   </row>
</data>
```

Then, use the following XSLT to transform it to Excel XML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
   <xsl:template match="/data">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
         <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
      </xsl:processing-instruction>

      <Workbook 
         xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
         xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
         xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
         xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
         xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
         <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>Bob</Author>
            <Created>2001-01-01T12:00:00Z</Created>
            <Version>1.0</Version>
         </DocumentProperties>
         <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>8835</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>11340</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>120</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
         </ExcelWorkbook>
         <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
               <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
               <Borders/>
               <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"/>
               <Interior/>
               <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00"/>
               <Protection/>
            </Style>
         </Styles>
         <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <ss:Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
               <xsl:attribute name="ss:ExpandedColumnCount">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(row[1]/cell)"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="ss:ExpandedRowCount">
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(row)"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
            </ss:Table>
            <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
               <PageSetup>
                  <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
                  <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
                  <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
               </PageSetup>
               <Print>
                  <ValidPrinterInfo/>
                  <PaperSizeIndex>9</PaperSizeIndex>
                  <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
                  <VerticalResolution>0</VerticalResolution>
               </Print>
               <Selected/>
               <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
               <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
            </WorksheetOptions>
         </Worksheet>
      </Workbook>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <Row>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="cell"/>
      </Row>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="cell" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
      <Cell>
         <Data>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="number(.) =.">
                  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">Number</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">String</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </Data>
      </Cell>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although this example only creates one worksheet, you should be able to see how straight-forward it is to create multiple sheets. Simply output another **Worksheet** element for each work sheet within the document you need.

It can be useful to create a spreadsheet manually in Microsoft Excel, and then **Save As** Mircosoft Excel XML format, and then have a look at it in Notepad to see the XML it creates. This could be useful for seeing how it does things like formatting, or column widths.